# How to remove space between table td border

Tags: html, css, html-table

After one year experience of `html` `js`,`css` was taught me this happens when I don't put `border-collapse:collapse` on table container it happens

```js
setInterval(function(){
$('table').toggleClass('collapse')
},2000)
```

```css
table{
width:100%;
}
td,th{
border:1px solid black
}
.collapse{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<thead>
<tr>
<th>header 1</th>
<th>header 2</th>
<th>header 3</th>
<th>header 4</th>
<th>header 5</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>

</tr>


</tbody>

</table>

<i>You will see there is space between border. At that moment i was asking how to collapse those space between border.
So 1 dude tell me to put <pre style='color:red;font-weight:600'>border-collapse:collapse</pre> on table tag. Reason why i edit this question is for later for help for poor souls like me like green as grass on html Hope you understand this 
</i>
```

[image]

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>9</th>
    <th>10</th>
    <th>11</th>
    <th>12</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
</tbody>
```

Css just have `border-bottom: 1px solid "color code"` like this picture:

[image]

This is the  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wngu28m4/). How can I solve this?

All borders are not whole. And borders like in this picture cut.

Comment: Can I see whole code?

Comment: I can't understand the picture. What is the relevance of that to the code?

Comment: Provide more code

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry for it but cant you guys see those td borders has cut by each td

Comment: So much hype train hmm

Comment: You need to post more code. For both html and css you are using. `border-bottom: 1px solid "color code"` is not enough to drill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to remove the spacing between cells:

1. Define `table` as :

   `<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`
2. Add CSS:

   ```
   table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   ```

   OR:

   ```
   table {            
       border-spacing: 0;
   }
   ```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sahero/wngu28m4/1/

Comment: I tried border-collapse: but i did to corrupt my page, Border-spacing: 0 ; did a job